# Class method as a decorator

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have a class where I have multiple methods. I want to use one of the methods as a decorator for other methods. For this I am using following syntax:

```
@self.action
def execute(self,req):
```

where action is other method in my class. But it doesn't work and throws exception as

```
name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: By the moment, when the function created and decorated, the instance (even the class) does not exist yet, so you can't do it like that. What could be done instead, depends on what `action` is supposed to do.

Comment: action is a base class method. There are many derived classes and each derived class has a method which performs a specific operation. Before and after each operation, I need to do certain operations which I have written in base class methods. But in every derived class, I have to repeat that code. Thus I have created a method called action in the base class which will act as a decorator.

Comment: @gliese581g: Does the decorator need to know about what class the method is being defined on?

Comment: @MartijnPieters:No it doesn't.

Comment: @gliese581g: then why make it part of the class *at all*?

Comment: @MartijnPieters This decorator is going to perform the tasks which are specific to this base class and I want to set various member values inside.

Comment: @gliese581g: the *wrapper* (what you return from the decorator) will still be handled as a method, so when called `self` will be available at that time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:I want your suggestion about where do I put this decorator. As I have said this decorator is going to perform actions which are specific to the base and derived classes. It is not useful for any other classes. Thus I have put it in base class. Does it make any sense? Please let me know if it is a right decision?  Also, as I had to make it a static method, it is accessible from outside. I don't want that and it should only be accessible from base and derived classes. Is it possible for static methods?

Comment: @gliese581g: Just make it a function *next* to the `Base` class, and import it together with `Base`. Give it a leading underscore name so that `from module import *` will not include it and any Python developer worth its salt will recognize it as a private utility function.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use a *method* of the class while defining it; there is no `self` within the class nor is the class 'baked' yet to even access any class.

You can treat methods as functions to use as a decorator:

```
class SomeClass():
    def action(func):
        # decorate
        return wrapper

    @action
    def execute(self, req):
        # something
```

If `action` is defined on a base class, then you'd have to refer to the name via the base class:

```
class Base():
    @staticmethod
    def action(func):
        # decorate
        return wrapper

class Derived(Base):
    @Base.action
    def execute(self, req):
        # something
```

For Python 2, you'd have to make `action` a static method here, as otherwise you get an unbound method that'll complain you cannot call it without an instance as the first argument. In Python 3, you can leave off the `@staticmethod` decorator there, at least for the purposes of the decorator.

But note that `action` cannot then be used as a method directly; perhaps it should not be part of the class at all at that point. It is not part of the end-user API here, presumably the decorator is not used by consumers of the instances of these classes.

Comment: Sidestepping the issue of whether `action` should be part of the class, `action` could be defined as a static method (`@staticmethod def action(func)...`).

Comment: @chepner: sure, but that doesn't make the static method any more useful.

Comment: what if we want to call another method of `SomeClass` in `action`? We cannot access methods and properties of an instance of `SomeClass`  using `self.`

Comment: @ddzzbbwwmm: there is no class yet when running the code inside the class body. You can treat it as a local namespace in a function instead, so reference other functions by their name.

Answer (score 1):

Just beware that both the decorator and the decorated function are unbound methods, so you can only access the self (or cls for classmethods) in the inner scope of the decorator, and must manually bind the decorated method to the instance bound in the inner decorator.

```py
class A:
    x = 5
    y = 6

    def decorate(unbound):
        def _decorator(self):
            bound = unbound.__get__(self)
            return bound() * self.x
        return _decorator

    @decorate
    def func(self):
        return self.y

A().func()  # 30!!
```

Still trying to wrap my head around how decorators could be inherited and overridden.

---

Beware that for the decorator to work it can't be bound to an instance. That is: there is no way to make this work

```
a = A()

@a.decorate
def func(*args):
    return 1
```

Despite this pattern is [much more common](https://github.com/pallets/flask#a-simple-example) than the asked here.

At this point the question raises: is it a method at all or just code that you happen to hide in a class?

The only way to prevent the decorator being wrongfully bound is to declare it as a staticmethod, but then it must be in a previous super class because to be used it must be bound to the static class reference which would not be yet defined, just as the self.

```
class A:
    x = 1

    @staticmethod
    def decorate(unbound):
        def _decorator(self):
            bound = unbound.__get__(self)
            return bound() * self.x
        return _decorator

class B(A):

    @A.decorate
    def func(self):
        return 1

class C():
    x = 2
    @B.decorate
    def func(self):
        return 1

a = A()

class D():
    x = 3

    @a.decorate
    def func(self):
        return 1

B().func()  # 1
C().func()  # 2
D().func()  # 3
```

But as you can see, there is no way for the decorator to use the state of its own class. `class A` from this last example just happens to be a mixin with a default `x` variable and an "unrelated" static decorator.

So, again, is it a method?

---

To overcome all of this, you can bind the staticmethod in your same class to an arbitrary type. Namely, the builtin `type` will do.

```
class A:
    x = 1

    @staticmethod
    def decorate(unbound):
        def _decorator(self):
            bound = unbound.__get__(self)
            return bound() * self.x
        return _decorator

    @decorate.__get__(type)
    def func(self):
        return 1

class B:
    x = 2

    @A.decorate
    def func(self):
        return 1

class C:
    x = 3

    @(A().decorate)  # Only for Python 3.9+, see PEP-614
    def func(self):
        return 1

A().func()  # 1
B().func()  # 2
C().func()  # 3
```

But this features too much magic for my taste. And still not a method for my gut.

Answer (score 0):

In python "self" is passed to instance methods as an argument (the first), "self" is just a convention is possible to call it "foobarbaz" (of course it would be silly)… the point is that, from the outside "self" is not defined (because its scope is the method)… you can't decorate class methods with other class methods, instead you have to write a separate class!